# Restrictions around 30x redirects in a service worker's fetch handler

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a basic service worker that returns an offline page when there is no internet connection. Anywhere where the website returns a 302 redirect, the site will break on account of the service worker, regardless of being online of offline.

The service worker:

```
'use strict';

var cache_key = 'offline_cache_v18';

this.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cache_key).then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/offline.html'
            ]);
        })
    );
});

this.addEventListener('fetch', event => {

    if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' || (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')) ) {

        event.respondWith(
            fetch(event.request.url).catch(error => {

                return caches.match('/offline.html');

            })
        );

    } else {

        event.respondWith(caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {

            return response || fetch(event.request);


        }));
    }

});
```

A page that breaks the service worker:

```
<?php header('Location: /'); ?>
```

Expected result: pages to load as usual, except when offline, where offline.html should be presented.

Actual result: The site fails to load entirely on pages that respond with a 302 redirect, citing 'This site can’t be reached'. The console also reports: 'The FetchEvent resulted in a network error response: a redirected response was used for a request whose redirect mode is not "follow".'

Tried: checking the response code with response.status, and also tried switching the code to use the 'workbox' library. Also tried {redirect: 'follow'} parameters but it seems to be getting quite advanced now for something so simple. All the 'offline page' tutorials seem to have this same bug.

Answer (score 4):

*The underlying security restriction is explained in detail at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=658249*

This issue crops up for navigation requests, since those requests use a [`redirect` mode](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-redirect-mode) of `'manual'`. (Most other types of requests will have a `redirect` mode of `'follow'`, which means that a redirected HTTP 30x response can be used to fulfill them.)

You can detect whether or not you have a `Response` object that was generated by following an HTTP 30x redirect by checking its [`redirected`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-redirected) property.

Putting that all together: how do you use a `Response` object that was generated as part of a 30x redirect to satisfy a `fetch` event for a navigation request? The answer is to "clean" the redirected response first, by creating a new (mostly identical) `Response` object, but which will have the `redirected` property set to `false`.

```
async function cleanRedirect(response) {
  const clonedResponse = response.clone();

  return new Response(await clonedResponse.blob(), {
    headers: clonedResponse.headers,
    status: clonedResponse.status,
    statusText: clonedResponse.statusText,
  });
}
```

You can use this by checking whether `event.request.redirect === 'manual'` inside of a `fetch` handler. If so, before calling `event.respondWith(response)`, check to see if `response.redirected` is `true`. If it is, then pass that redirected response to `await cleanRedirect()` first.

(This code is adapted from Workbox's [implementation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/93cc3cce6c9c9741d25f098fe73e9da943b57f25/packages/workbox-precaching/src/utils/cleanRedirect.ts). Workbox will automatically "clean" any redirected responses for URLs that are precached, but it does not perform automatic cleaning on URLs that are cached at runtime.)

Comment: Great answer! I never would have figured this out lol